# Import icon in Metro Studio 5

Tags: syncfusion

I am trying to get icon for my Windows Phone 8 application but cannot find suitable icon in Syncfusion Metro Studio 5. I found it on the net. How can I get it in Metro Studio to modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, we do not have the facility to import icon and you can expect the feature in future releases. Besides, If you need any icon please let us know, we will definitely provide you the Metrop file :-)

Regards,
Tamilarasi Marudhan